# Вызов подскрипта Python

Tags: python, консоль, if, модули

Я создаю калькулятор, который состоит из главного скрипта и четырёх под-скриптов. В начале программы надо выбрать, какой будет работать скрипт. Только открываю программу, но она не задаёт вопрос, какой выбрать скрипт, и сразу включает первый под-скрипт. Вот код главного скрипта:

```
import Addition, Division, Multiplication, Subtraction, sys, os, time

ModulesNumbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

print('''Напишите "1", если хотите узнать сумму двух чисел. 
\nНапишите "2", если хотите узнать разность двух чисел.
\nНапишите "3", если хотите узнать произведение двух чисел.
\nНапишите "4", если хотите узнать частное двух чисел.\n\r''')

user = sys.stdin.readline()

while not user in ModulesNumbers:
    if user == '1':
        Addition.Addition()
    if user == '2':
        Subtraction.Subtraction()
    if user == '3':
        Multiplication.Multiplication()
    if user == '4':
        Division.Division()
```

Вот 1 подскрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# +
import time, os, sys
print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи первое слагаемое, а потом второе 
слагаемое, и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
print('\nВведи первое слагаемое \n\r')
first_term = sys.stdin.readline()

print('\nВведи второе слагаемое \n\r')
second_term = sys.stdin.readline()

first_term = int(first_term)
second_term = int(second_term)

result = first_term + second_term

print(str(result))
print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
time.sleep(60)
sys.exit()
```

вот 2 подскрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ÷
import time, os, sys
print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи делимое, а потом делитель, 
и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
print('\nВведи первое слагаемое \n\r')
dividend = sys.stdin.readline()

print('\nВведи второе слагаемое \n\r')
divider = sys.stdin.readline()

dividend = int(dividend)
divider = int(divider)

result = dividend / divider

print(str(result))
print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
time.sleep(60)
sys.exit()
```

вот 3 подскрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ·
import time, os, sys
print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи первый множитель, а потом второй 
множитель, и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
print('\nВведи первый множитель \n\r')
first_multiplier = sys.stdin.readline()

print('\nВведи второе множитель \n\r')
second_multiplier = sys.stdin.readline()

first_multiplier = int(first_multiplier)
second_multiplier = int(second_multiplier)

result = first_multiplier * second_multiplier

print(str(result))
print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
time.sleep(60)
sys.exit()
```

вот 4 подскрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -
import time, os, sys
print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи уменьшаемое, а потом вычитаемое, 
и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
print('\nВведи уменьшаемое \n\r')
minuend = sys.stdin.readline()

print('\nВведи вычитаемое \n\r')
subtrahend = sys.stdin.readline()

minuend = int(minuend)
subtrahend = int(subtrahend)

result = minuend - subtrahend

print(str(result))
print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
time.sleep(60)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: зачем `sys.stdin.readline()`? зачем так сложно? ведь можно просто `input()`

Comment: Проще всего обернуть код в каждом скрипте в функции, и эти функции импортировать и вызывать. Но `sys.exit()` нужно убрать, иначе это будет завершать вашу программу целиком.

Comment: Но, правда, я так и хотел, чтобы через минуту было автозавершение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать так.

Главный скрипт:

```py
import os, sys, time
from Addition import Addition
from Division import Division
from Multiplication import Multiplication
from Subtraction import Subtraction

import Addition, Division, Multiplication, Subtraction, sys, os, time

ModulesNumbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

print('''Напишите "1", если хотите узнать сумму двух чисел. 
\nНапишите "2", если хотите узнать разность двух чисел.
\nНапишите "3", если хотите узнать произведение двух чисел.
\nНапишите "4", если хотите узнать частное двух чисел.\n\r''')

user = input()
#     not не нужен!
while user in ModulesNumbers:
    if user == '1':
        Addition.Addition()
    if user == '2':
        Subtraction.Subtraction()
    if user == '3':
        Multiplication.Multiplication()
    if user == '4':
        Division.Division()
```

1 подскрипт:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# +
import time, os, sys
def Addition():
    print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи первое слагаемое, а потом второе 
слагаемое, и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
    print('\nВведи первое слагаемое \n\r')
    first_term = sys.stdin.readline()

    print('\nВведи второе слагаемое \n\r')
    second_term = sys.stdin.readline()

    first_term = int(first_term)
    second_term = int(second_term)

    result = first_term + second_term

    print(str(result))
    print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
    time.sleep(60)
    sys.exit()
```

2 подскрипт:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ÷
import time, os, sys
def Division():
    print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи делимое, а потом делитель, 
и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
    print('\nВведи первое слагаемое \n\r')
    dividend = sys.stdin.readline()

    print('\nВведи второе слагаемое \n\r')
    divider = sys.stdin.readline()

    dividend = int(dividend)
    divider = int(divider)

    result = dividend / divider

    print(str(result))
    print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
    time.sleep(60)
    sys.exit()
```

3 подскрипт:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ·
import time, os, sys
def Multiplication():
    print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи первый множитель, а потом второй 
множитель, и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
    print('\nВведи первый множитель \n\r')
    first_multiplier = sys.stdin.readline()

    print('\nВведи второе множитель \n\r')
    second_multiplier = sys.stdin.readline()

    first_multiplier = int(first_multiplier)
    second_multiplier = int(second_multiplier)

    result = first_multiplier * second_multiplier

    print(str(result))
    print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
    time.sleep(60)
    sys.exit()
```

4 подскрипт:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -
import time, os, sys
def Subtraction():
    print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи уменьшаемое, а потом вычитаемое, 
и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''')
    print('\nВведи уменьшаемое \n\r')
    minuend = sys.stdin.readline()

    print('\nВведи вычитаемое \n\r')
    subtrahend = sys.stdin.readline()

    minuend = int(minuend)
    subtrahend = int(subtrahend)

    result = minuend - subtrahend

    print(str(result))
    print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
    time.sleep(60)
    sys.exit()
```

Я просто обернул главные строки кода в функции. Проблема была в том, что при импорте модуля, весь код модуля исполняется автоматически. Соответственно, и ваши скрипты в подскриптах будут выполняться автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

не корректное исспользование модулей.
суть вашей ошибки в том, что импортируемые файлы, так же являются исполняемыми, те вы на это надеятесь.
модули питона, это файлы питона, которые должны предоставлять, набор функций или\и классов, в вашем же случае при импорте контроль передаётся импортируемубля модулю. то есть в импортируемом файле нельзя\не желательно как-либо взаимоедйствовать с пользователем(по средствам графики-или input) там должны быть только названия функций или классов.

то есть во время импорта, исполняемый(главный) файл передаёт управление модулю(кривому) и он становится на время главным файлом.

вот варианты решения: 1) питоновский- обернуть весь код в импортированых файлах в функцию (типа майн или дивизион итп) и импортировать её, либо исспользовать переменную `__all__=['function_name_for_import']` и импортировать весь модуль. 2) сишный применить аналог функции инклуд, то есть запросить у пользователя инфу, затем исполнить файл, как будто он написан в главном файле

```
#runpy.run_path('file',globals())
def include(file):
    globals().update(run_path(file,globals())
вот код для второго варинта
```

#main.py
import runpy
#runpy.run_path('file',globals())
def include(file):
globals().update(run_path(file,globals()))
result=int(input('чё хотел то?'))#int здесь как фильтр, чтобы отсечь буквы
files={'1':'name_of_file','2':'division',....}
include(files(str(result))) #str тут тк есть соглашение о наименовании

import time, os, sys
#print('''Привет! Это калькулятор. Введи первое слагаемое, а потом второе
слагаемое, и программа выведет результат. Чтобы сделать ещё одно вычисление,
перезапустите программу.''') #нежалательно юзать принт в модуле
def mod():
print('\nВведи первое слагаемое \n\r')
first_term = sys.stdin.readline()

print('\nВведи второе слагаемое \n\r')
second_term = sys.stdin.readline()

first_term = int(first_term)
second_term = int(second_term)

result = first_term + second_term

print(str(result))
'''print('\nПерезапустите программу, чтобы снова сделать вычисление. Через 1 минуту произойдёт автовыключение.')
time.sleep(60)
sys.exit()''' #это можно вынести в главный файл чтобы не писать четыре раза

````
```import a,b,c
r=input('')

#way a
a.eval(r) #но это очень не безопасно, но просто
#way b
map={'1':a...} #без кавычек
map[r].name_of_main_function()
````